# Formating MYSQL datetime in Angular doesn't work in Safari browser

Tags: angularjs, datetime, safari

I want to format MYSQL datetime (eg. `2017-02-07 22:58:22`), so I've found, that it's necessary to convert it to ISO format with this filter first:

```
angular.module('datePipe',[]).filter('dateToISO', function() {
  return function(input) {
    input = new Date(input).toISOString();
    return input;
  };
});
```

This works in chrome and also in firefox, but not in safari :( There it throws error:

> Error: Invalid Date toISOString@[native code]

How can I fix this error? Thank you :)

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. Did you fix it?

Comment: look at the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

**html**

```
<div class="date-left">{{ newie.created_at | dateParser | date:'d. M. yyyy' }}</div>
```

and here's dateParser

```
angular.module('datePipe',[]).filter('dateParser', function() {
    return function(input) {
    var year = input.substr(0,4);
    var month = input.substr(5,2);
    var day = input.substr(8,2);

    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
  };
})
```

I just wanted to display date only :)